# Bitcoin why do they need miners?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, bitcoin

Why does bitcoin have miners? Why don't the users mine their own blocks. I understand it may be to ensure the currency is traded, but in any non transaction blockchain case do you need miners or is it fine to let the users mine their own blocks?

I couldn't find any reason as to why bitcoin really needs miners other than for adding coin to the market.

Comment: It's not a programming question and thus off-topic. Even worse, there's a whole [stack exchange site](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) devoted to bitcoin!

Comment: I looked through stack exchange, couldn't find anything for bitcoin. My bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only distinction between a user and a miner is that a miner is doing computational work to get bitcoin, and a user is using bitcoin to make transactions. A user could easily do the computational work as well, but then they would just be a miner. The reason not everyone is a miner is because not everyone wants to do computational work, many just want to make transactions.